# Linux CentOS 6 ssh slow login/doesn't work

Tags: ssh, sshd

I am at my wits end trying to troubleshoot a slow login on a CentOS 6.10 system. This just started within the last week. Logins are sometimes fast and other times hang for around 15-60 seconds before it works or times out and gives some error message. We are running Powerbroker for AD login but I don't think that's related to the issue.

UseDNS and GSSAPI* is all set to no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and it it still slow and unreliable. Also when trying to login with a local user account it hangs indefinitely at send packet type 50(or other sometimes 61). This occurs with password auth and an account with a keypair for auth as well. With password login after a long wait the password prompt will come up and then hang and never login (pass is correct). In /var/log/secure it stops at "Postponed keyboard-interactive for veeam from 10.12.103.54 port 49814 ssh". Password ssh -vvv always hangs at send packet type: xyz" it changes but only ever shows postponed in the logs.

We have a duplicate system and all the pam modules in /etc/pam.d/* all seem to look the same but we haven't made any changes since this occurred randomly.

Comment: I should also note the system has a load average currently of under .1 and has no disk activity. Performance wise it should not be something that is causing this ram usage is also 20GB/256GB

Comment: Seems with UsePAM no local logins work again does anyome know which modules may be the culrpit? SSH as well as local terminal login with keybaord is slow and local logins wouldn't work